# How to pass variable from Java code to JSP and generate pop up of Yes and No and back to java on selection

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I have a JSP and a Java Class. Upon moving from previous page, the Java code is called via Action Class and I have to check a value in Database(which is done). Now I want to pass that variable in JSP, if the variable is empty then I need to give user option to proceed or not.

If proceed - go to next JSP , else stop in same JSP.

My Problem is how to pass a variable to Java to JSP and upon suitable selection of option call back Java to complete the process.

Comment: add it to your request - this is basic web application programming  - follow a tutorial on web application programming

Comment: if you are using a **Form** class then you can set it to form property and can use it in JSP

Comment: thanks, I did that.. but now question is how after selection continue back to Java where I left ?

Answer (score 0):

On Click YES button you want to again call Action method.

You can create simple java-script function and provide Ajax call to your appropriate action name.

This javascript function call,onClick event of your jsp button.

Example

```
function actionCall() {
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: params,
        url: 'Action url'+'Action Name',
        error: function(o) {
            //error code
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //Success code  
        }
    });
}
```